# Leer Json en un for de una consulta php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo un petición `getjson` a una tabla en `MySQL` por medio de `PHP`.

Lo que necesito hacer el poder leer la respuesta mediante un `for` en `javascript` para sacar unos datos.

Tengo esta consulta en `PHP`:

```
 <?php
    $link= mysql_connect('localhost', 'root')
      or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db('sk_modular_divisiones') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
      $query= "SELECT sk_componente, sk_ancho FROM sk_standar WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-148' AND sk_grupo = 'APISO' AND sk_componente = 'ParaExt'";
      $result = mysql_query($query)
                or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");
                mysql_close();
      echo json_encode($result);
      //liberar resultador
      mysql_free_result($result);
      //Cerrar la conexión
      mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

y deseo convertirla en un `JSON` por medio de un `getjson`

```
var url="json.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
  // loop through the members here
  $.each(json.dinamica,function(i,dat)
}
```

y por medio de este for leer los datos que me trajo el `json` para sacar un valor

```
for (var j = 0; j < (dinamica.length) - 1; j++) {
  if (dinamica[j].sk_ancho < TPARAL && dinamica[j + 1].sk_ancho >= TPARAL && dinamica[j].sk_componenete == PCENTRAL) {
    resultPajustCentral.push(dinamica[j].sk_ancho);
  }
}
```

para meterlo en una tabla de `HTML`

```
document.getElementById("pac").innerHTML = resultPajustCentral[i];
```

Esto es lo que me debe traer el `JSON` de la consulta `PHP`:

```
var dinamica = [{
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 30
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 70
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 120
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 170
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 220
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 270
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 320
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 370
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 420
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 470
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 520
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 570
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 620
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 670
}, {
    "sk_componenete": "Paral",
    "sk_ancho": 720
}];
```

Comment: cual es el problema?

Comment: el getjson no me esta trayendo nada de la consulta que hago con php.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar qué valor tiene la variable `json` que recibes en el `Javascript`?

Comment: si accedes directamente a el php o, si no puedes acceder directamente,  que te responde si le haces un curl a tu php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero has esta correccion en el php

```
<?php
        $link= mysql_connect('localhost', 'root')
          or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
          mysql_select_db('sk_modular_divisiones') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
          $query= "SELECT sk_componente, sk_ancho FROM sk_standar WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-148' AND sk_grupo = 'APISO' AND sk_componente = 'ParaExt'";
          $result = mysql_query($query)
                    or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");
                    mysql_close();
       echo json_encode($result,true); <------------AQUI AGREGA EL TRUE
       //liberar resultador
       mysql_free_result($result);
       //Cerrar la conexión
       mysql_close($link);
?>
```

despues deberas hacer los siguiente

```
var url="json.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
  // loop through the members here
  $.each(json,function(i,dat){
      var sk_componenete= dat['sk_componenete'];
      var sk_ancho = dat['sk_ancho'];
  });
}
```

de esta forma podras obtener la informacion que necesitas y almacenarla donde la quieres

Answer (score 0):

En tu codigo no veo en que parte realizas el FETCH del resultado, deberias hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$link= mysql_connect('localhost', 'root')
  or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('sk_modular_divisiones') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
  $query= "SELECT sk_componente, sk_ancho FROM sk_standar WHERE sk_tipo = 'ALTU-148' AND sk_grupo = 'APISO' AND sk_componente = 'ParaExt'";
  $result = mysql_query($query)
            or die("Ocurrio un error en la consulta SQL");
            mysql_close();

  //ARREGLO PARA ALMACENAR EL RESULTADO Y CONVERTIRLO EN JSON
  $array = array(); 
  while( $datos = mysql_fetch_array($resultado) ){
    $array[] = $datos;
  }
  echo json_encode($array);

  //liberar resultador
  mysql_free_result($result);
  //Cerrar la conexión
  mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Ya con esto podras obtener el resultado en ajax:

```
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url:"xurl.php",
 data:$('form').serialize(),
 dataType:"JSON",
 success:function(r){
   console.log(r);
 },
 error:function(err){
  console.log(err.responseText);
 }
});
```